# Set instance variable to None inside method if condition not met

Tags: python, set

I have a method that goes over an Excel sheet that parses out data to a set. However, if that data is not present in a sheet, I want it to return `None` rather than an empty set. Example:

```py
import xlrd

def scanSheet(self, sheet):

   kwds = ['kwd1','kwd2'] #pretend these are header names for the columns
   mySet = set()

   if not sheet:
       return self.dataset #set to None in __init__

    for row in range(sheet.nrows):
        for col in range(sheet.ncols):
            if str(sheet.cell_value(row, col)).lower() in kwds:
                sheetLength = list(range(row+1, sheet.nrows)) #ignore the header row

                for idx in range(len(sheetLength):
                    data = sheet.cell(sheetLength[i], col).value
                    mySet.add(data)

    self.dataset = mySet
```

If there is data, it returns a set and everything is fooly cooly. If there isn't data though, it will return, as stated above, `set()`. Is it possible to have it set to `None` if the list is empty rather than `set()`? The reason that the `if` statement at the beginning of the function wouldn't trigger a `None` value for the class variable, is a case of the Excel sheet existing, but not containing the data that is deemed interesting.

Comment: You *could* just check for that explicitly - but `special cases aren't special enough`. I predict you will write simpler and more easily understood code if you *expect* the method to return an empty set in this case - and perhaps also use an empty set for your initialization rather than `None`.

Comment: An empty set sounds like perfectly reasonable value for this function to return. Unless you have some distinction in mind between `{}` and `None`, I would rethink doing this. (And if there *is* a distinction, raising an exception may be more appropriate than returning `None`.)

Comment: You say "class variable" in the title, but `self.dataset #set to None in __init__` is an instance variable. Should the title be changed?

Comment: Since you don't have a return statement at the bottom of the function, if there is data, it returns `None`. Should there be a `return self.dataset`  at the bottom? In the case of `if not sheet` should that always return `None` or a previously discovered `self.dataset` from the last sheet that happened to have been queried?

Comment: As for "not containing the data thas is deemed interesting" - suppose the sheet has `kwds` but no data, so `mySet` has no entries. Does that count as interesting or should all cases of empty `mySet` be considered `None`?

Comment: Sorry all, I am not very particular with my jargon (I'm working on it). Return is the wrong word, I guess "reset value to" is a better way to phrase it? It's a "setter" function, but since I can never seem to get decorators to work, I do the JS set/gets (which I know is unpythonic, but working code is better than pretty code, imo). The `if` statement will return `None` because that is what `self.dataset` is instantiated to. @tdelaney if it has no data, it is not interesting (to my work) so I would rather it return `None` than empty set. All things considered I don't think I need to change it.

Comment: I just prefer the output of `None` because of how the data is stored, and because it will be viewed by non-software oriented people, I want it to be as readable as possible to them. I don't want to raise an exception, because I'm using this whole script as a tool to iterate over a folder full of variously formatted Excel files and have the expectation there will be edge cases. Perhaps I'm trying to be too perfect and getting bogged down on that. Thanks for the replies, but I think I'll close the question (if I have that power?) and do a Falsy eval func as Patrick showed below. Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As empty sets are Falsy you can do

```
def func(yourset):
    return yourset or None
```

in case `yourset` is empty (aka `False`y) - it will return `None`.

```
print(func(set([42])))
print(func(set()))
```

Output:

```
{42} 
None
```

See [truth value testing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing)